# WebGl Spotlight Shader

Tags: webgl, shader

I have been trying to program a basic webgl spotlight shader, but no matter how hard I try, I cannot get the spotlights position to be relative to the world.
The code that I am currently using is below, I have tried almost every coordinate frame that I can to get this working, but no matter what I do, I only get partially correct results. 
For example if I switch to world coordinates the spotlights position will be correct, but it will only reflect off one object, or if I use the view space the light will work but it's position is relative to the camera.
In it's current state, the spotlight seems to be relative to each objects frame. (Not sure why.) 
Any help in solving helping this issue is greatly appreciated.

**Vertex Shader:**

```
attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec4 vNormal;
attribute vec2 vTexCoord;

varying vec3 L, E, N,D;
varying vec2 fTexCoord;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 NormalMatrix;
uniform mat4 View;

uniform vec4 lightPosition;
uniform vec4 lightDirection;
uniform vec3 Eye;

void main(){
    L= (modelViewMatrix * lightPosition).xyz; //Light position in eye coordinates
    E = (modelViewMatrix * vPosition).xyz;    //Vertex position in eye coordinates.
    //Normal position in eye coordinate. Transpose(Inverse(modelViewMatrix) * vNormal.
    N=(NormalMatrix * vNormal).xyz;
    D=lightDirection.xyz;//Light direction
    fTexCoord=vTexCoord;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vPosition;
}
```

**Fragment Shader:**

```
precision mediump float;
uniform vec4 lDiffuseColor;
uniform vec4 lSpecular;
uniform vec4 lAmbientColor;
uniform float lShininess;

varying vec3 L,E,N,D;
const float lExponent=2.0;
const float lCutoff=0.867;
vec3 lWeight=vec3(0,0,0);

void main(){

    vec3 vtoLS=normalize(L - E);//Vector to light source from vertex.
    float Ks=pow(max(dot(normalize(N),vtoLS),0.0),lShininess);
    vec3 specular=Ks* lSpecular.xyz;
    float diffuseWeight=max(dot(normalize(N), -vtoLS),0.0);
    vec3 diffuse=diffuseWeight * lDiffuseColor.xyz;

    if(diffuseWeight >0.0){
        float lEffect= dot(normalize(D),normalize(-vtoLS));
        if(lEffect > lCutoff){
            lEffect= pow(lEffect,Ks);
            vec3 reflection= normalize(reflect(-vtoLS,normalize(N)));
            vec3 vEye=-normalize(E);
            float rdotv=max(dot(reflection,vEye),0.0);
            float specularWeight=pow(rdotv,lShininess);
            lWeight= (lEffect * diffuse.xyz  + lEffect * specular.xyz) + vec3(0.5,0,0);
        }   
    }
    lWeight+=lAmbientColor.xyz;
    gl_FragColor=vec4(lWeight.rgb,1);

}
```

Current Output: http://sta.sh/012uh5hwwlse

Comment: Having been through this exercise myself recently a useful debug technique is to set the gl_FragColor to different uniform/varying you are passing in to pinpoint which is incorrect. For example, suppose if your vNormals are in view space then every mesh that is facing towards you should be blue (0, 0, 1);

Comment: Also looking at your code, shouldnt `D=lightDirection.xyz;//Light direction` be in view space/ eye coordinates as well?

Comment: That seems to have worked, or so it appears.

Comment: On second examination, this only partly works... :(